# What is the purpose of 5, 9, 15, and 20 Volt rails in the USB PD spec?

Tags: usb

The reason for 5 Volts is obvious, baseline compatibility with USB protocol, lowest common denominator.  Higher voltage options were required to deliver the wattage required by modern devices.

Allowing a PD charger to deliver a continuously variable voltage range, for example passing through vehicle supply voltage, or LiPo pack voltage, seems like a simple efficient method of achieving that goal.  Yet, my reading of the USB PD spec seems to prohibit that option.

First, is my understanding correct, that such pass through via USB Type C PD 3.0 is a violation of the spec?
Please suggest any way(within PD 3.0 spec, perhaps an alt mode) to pass vehicle supply voltage(always < 20v), current limited to 5A, from a charger/OBDII device I am designing, via USB Type C full featured cable, to an Android device I am also designing.

Second, why are 4 fixed voltage levels required to be provided by charger instead of a continuous range(as in Qualcomm Quick Charge)?

Third, what are the advantages for a charger to supply each of those specific voltages, 9, 15, 20v.

As I understand it, maximum wattage 100W was chosen due to international safety requirements.

Any answer that states the reason for the voltages is to maintain safe current within existing cables must also explain how this is relevant given that PD is only allowed over USB Type C cables and that 5A is allowed at 20V, but only 3A at the lower voltages over the same cable.

Comment: Why this or that standard is never a good question. One can trot out observations, that this or that voltage is used here or there, but without the minutes of the standards setting meetings, and knowledge of the horse-trading that went on over dinners and drinks, the only answer is 'why not?'. The 100W is just as arbitrary. (a) is perhaps more worthwhile to attempt than (b). Perhaps they didn't think of a continuous range, or bottled the complexity, or wanted it 'easier' to use than Qualcomm's (or did Qualcomm release QC second?) who knows?

Comment: @Neil_UK I vehemently disagree.  It is important to question standards, that is how they are improved.  Someone has "the minutes of the standards setting meetings" and that would be a perfect answer to my question.  I am currently designing USB Type C devices and have the option to choose the PD standard, or not.  I asked the question to see if there is some purpose behind the voltage choices that I have not yet appreciated.  Something that will affect my decision.  The standard is so important and so complex that I doubt it was set arbitrarily.  I assume I must be missing something.

Comment: I agree with Neil, @slomobile. There will be no minutes that explain what went through the heads of people participating in that round table meeting or those teleconferences, however the PD standard was achieved. All you'd see would be who was publicly pushing for what, but you'd never see what was being negotiated behind the curtains, nor the motivation of the people.

Comment: You may be upset by the situation, but that's the way it is. I have participated in many standards setting organisations, and to be frank, in most cases, to call it arbitrary would be to slander the word arbitrary. USB is the result of 'coopertition', the cooperation of several organisations who are in commercial competition with each other. Each has an axe to grind, and they horse-trade this bit of IP for that bit of kudos, and end up with something far more complicated and arbitrary than it needs to be. But, it seems to get some sort of job done. Good luck.

Comment: What kind of difference does it make for you, whether it is 5,9,12,or 20V? Just do what the standard needs. Communicating 2 bits of information to a source power supply is much less expensive than to have the whole multi-bit DAC for arbitrary voltage.

Comment: I am not asking for opinion.  I am not asking for intrigue.  I am not upset by the situation.  I am just trying to understand the consequences of the situation.  I am asking for the engineering basis for those 4 voltages.  @Ali Chen was on the right track. 
 Perhaps expand on that and provide it as an answer.  This is my first time developing a USB Type C project.  My device will almost always be connected to vehicle power supply or 4S LiPo pack and draw >60W at times.  I was hoping to avoid the need to provide 4 regulated rails.  Please suggest edits to question if needed.

Comment: It is not clear what you are doing and/or asking. Are you designing a full-featured PD provider (host), of just a device that needs 60W, and therefore needs at least 20V@3A source of power? This power can be negotiated only over PD or Qualcomm QC. If this is a device, you need to be able to start with 5V, and only then negotiate a Contract with provider. You don't need "to provide 4 regulated rails" if you are designing a consuming device. But if you are designing both ends of the link, this is a different story.

Comment: I just noticed my edit characterized the 2 devices as charger and Android device because in general that is their role, however each is technically a full featured dual role device.  However, I want to avoid further edits until the reopen review is finished.

Comment: I am afraid the project you are working on is ill-conceived. First, the Type-C connector is nowhere of automotive grade thingy, too flimsy. Second, the PD is awfully complicated and, as you noted, doesn't fit well into usually not very-well regulated battery-based sources. While the idea of universal power delivery between everything and a kitchen sink looks appealing on marketing papers, I feel somehow that it won't fly at its current specification level, it already has 3 incompatible revisions. It might end as the OTG has ended down practically to a single ID pin.

Comment: I just learned there is a good non opinion based answer right in the spec itself which I must have overlooked in my initial reading.  power-data object (PDO) 10b
from section 7.1.3 USB Power Delivery Specification Revision 3.0, Version 1.1
The Variable Supply (non-Battery) PDO exposes very poorly regulated Sources.  The output voltage of a Variable Supply (non-Battery) Shall remain within the absolute maximum output voltage and the absolute minimum output voltage exposed in the Variable Supply PDO.  It would be nice if people stopped trying to close questions they don't know the answer to.